# MQTT not connect to broker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mqtt

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and one page of it must show my device state. I want get device state with MQTT from a broker (`broker.mqttdashboard.com`). I am using MQTTnet. I can not connect to broker , I have not username or password and I want to use a public channel to publish messages to broker by pressing a button. the button run `PublishMqttMsg` method and I want to give messages from broker.

I don't know how to connect to broker. Can anyone help me?

My controller code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Client.Connecting;
using MQTTnet.Client.Disconnecting;
using MQTTnet.Client.Options;
using MQTTnet.Client.Receiving;
using MQTTnet.Protocol;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MQTTnet.Diagnostics;
using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient;
using MQTTnet;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace WebApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class MqttController : Controller
    {
        private static IManagedMqttClient client;

        // GET: Mqtt
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var CurrentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ConnectAsync(CurrentUser, "broker.mqttdashboard.com", "", 8000, true);

           
            client.UseConnectedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully with MQTT Brokers.");
            });

            client.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from MQTT Brokers.");
            });

            client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string topic = e.ApplicationMessage.Topic;

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topic) == false)
                    {
                        string payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {topic}. Message Received: {payload}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
                }
            });



            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult SubscribeMqttMsg()
        {
            SubscribeAsync("test_topic/1");
            return View("Index");
        }


        public ActionResult PublishMqttMsg()
        {
            PublishAsync("test_topic/1", "test message");
            return View("Index");
        }




            /// <summary>
            /// Connect to broker.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>Task.</returns>
            public static async Task ConnectAsync(string user, string uri, string pass, int port, bool userSSL)
        {
            string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string mqttURI = uri;
            string mqttUser = user;
            string mqttPassword = pass;
            int mqttPort = port;
            bool mqttSecure = userSSL;

            var messageBuilder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
              //.WithClientId(clientId)
              //.WithCredentials(mqttUser, mqttPassword)
              .WithTcpServer(mqttURI, mqttPort)
             .WithCleanSession();
             

            var options = mqttSecure
              ? messageBuilder
                .WithTls()
                .Build()
              : messageBuilder
                .Build();

            var managedOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
              .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
              .WithClientOptions(options)
              .Build();

            client = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();

            await client.StartAsync(managedOptions);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Publish Message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="topic">Topic.</param>
        /// <param name="payload">Payload.</param>
        /// <param name="retainFlag">Retain flag.</param>
        /// <param name="qos">Quality of Service.</param>
        /// <returns>Task.</returns>
        public static async Task PublishAsync(string topic, string payload, bool retainFlag = true, int qos = 1) =>
          await client.PublishAsync(new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
            .WithTopic(topic)
            .WithPayload(payload)
            .WithQualityOfServiceLevel((MQTTnet.Protocol.MqttQualityOfServiceLevel)qos)
            .WithRetainFlag(retainFlag)
            .Build())
            ;


        /// <summary>
        /// Subscribe topic.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="topic">Topic.</param>
        /// <param name="qos">Quality of Service.</param>
        /// <returns>Task.</returns>
        public static async Task SubscribeAsync(string topic, int qos = 1) =>
          await client.SubscribeAsync(new TopicFilterBuilder()
            .WithTopic(topic)
            .WithQualityOfServiceLevel((MQTTnet.Protocol.MqttQualityOfServiceLevel)qos)
            .Build());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Port `8000` at `broker.hivemq.com` is the "Websocket Port" (so listening for MQTT over websockets connections). You are attempting to connect using a TCP client. Either change the port (to `1833`) or change:

```
var messageBuilder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
   .WithTcpServer(mqttURI, mqttPort)
   ...
```

to:

```
var messageBuilder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
   .WithWebSocketServer("broker.hivemq.com:8000/mqtt")
   ...
```

(see [the documentation](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/Client#websocket-connection)).